# How and why one would use Boost signals2?

Tags: c++, events, boost, boost-signals2

Learning c++ and trying to get familiar with some patterns. The [signals2 doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp164790912) clearly has a vast array of things I can do with slots and signals. What I don't understand is what types of applications (use cases) I should use it for.

I'm thinking along the lines of a state machine dispatching change events. Coming from a dynamically typed background (C#,Java etc) you'd use an event dispatcher or a static ref or a callback.

Are there difficulties in c++ with using cross-class callbacks? Is that essentially *why* signals2 exists?

One to the example cases is a document/view. How is this pattern better suited than say, using a vector of functions and calling each one in a loop, or say a lambda that calls state changes in registered listening class instances?

```
class Document
{
public:
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()>  signal_t;

public:
    Document()
    {}

    /* Connect a slot to the signal which will be emitted whenever
      text is appended to the document. */
    boost::signals2::connection connect(const signal_t::slot_type &subscriber)
    {
        return m_sig.connect(subscriber);
    }

    void append(const char* s)
    {
        m_text += s;
        m_sig();
    }

    const std::string& getText() const
    {
        return m_text;
    }

private:
    signal_t    m_sig;
    std::string m_text;
};
```

and

```
class TextView
{
public:
    TextView(Document& doc): m_document(doc)
    {
        m_connection = m_document.connect(boost::bind(&TextView::refresh, this));
    }

    ~TextView()
    {
        m_connection.disconnect();
    }

    void refresh() const
    {
        std::cout << "TextView: " << m_document.getText() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Document&               m_document;
    boost::signals2::connection  m_connection;
};
```

Comment: For one thing, **boost.signals2** was created before we had lambdas. Yes, now it's pretty much equivalent to having a `vector<function<void()>>`, and then `push_back()`ing lambdas. You might want some conveniences, like proper ordering of callbacks, signal-slot disconnection from either side, suspending signals, etc; that's when you will need some wrappers (that are surprisingly simple, [this is one I wrote](https://bitbucket.org/danielko/simplesignal/src/6557131d489f3d810a39fd4a2f0401bb0dab1922/include/SimpleSignal%2B%2B.hpp?at=default)).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Boost.Signals2` is not just "an array of callbacks", it has a lot of added value. IMO, the most important points are:

1. Thread-safety: several threads may connect/disconnect/invoke the same signal concurrently, without introducing race conditions. This is especially useful when communicating with an asynchronous subsystem, like an Active Object running in its own thread.
2. `connection` and `scoped_connection` handles that allow disconnection without having direct access to the `signal`. Note that this is the only way to disconnect incomparable slots, like `boost::function` (or `std::function`).
3. Temporary slot blocking. Provides a clean way to temporarily disable a listening module (eg. when a user requests to pause receiving messages in a view).
4. Automatic slot lifespan tracking: a signal disconnects automatically from "expired" slots. Consider the situation when a slot is a binder referencing a non-copyable object managed by `shared_ptr`s:

   ```
   shared_ptr<listener> l = listener::create();
   auto slot = bind(&listener::listen, l.get()); // we don't want aSignal_ to affect `listener` lifespan
   aSignal_.connect(your_signal_type::slot_type(slot).track(l)); // but do want to disconnect automatically when it gets destroyed
   ```

Certainly, one can re-implement all the above functionality on his own "using a vector of functions and calling each one in a loop" etc, but the question is how it would be better than `Boost.Signals2`. Re-inventing the wheel is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I guess an additional thing I don't understand is the const requirement. It forced me to do really bizarre (to me) things to compile. Is there a way to use signals cleanly without const restriction?

Comment: @FlavorScape What "const requirement" do you mean? Slots are accepted by const reference, because they are copied. But again, you can `bind` within a slot whatever you want, including parameters wrapped by `std::ref`.

Comment: +1 for _Note that this is the only way to disconnect **incomparable** slots, like boost::function (or std::function)_  - putting it in simple terms: unless one uses plain vanilla **function pointers**, there is no other way disconnecting from the signal

Comment: @Shmil The Cat well, not really: one can register a well-comparable function object as a slot, and then unregister it. The problem with `function<>` is that it's a type-erasure that can contain various things.