# Using publish-subscribe pattern for real application design

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, mainloop

I've decided to try out some design pattern to use it further in app development, and i'd like Publisher-Subscriber pattern. I've written some common mechanism basic classes like EventDispatcher and Subscriber, tried them in work, successfully sent event from first system and second system handled it, and app finished...I have one big misunderstanding: how to create some main Application class which will have main loop, also controlled by events (for example, close application when event APPLICATION_CLOSE handled)?
Here are basic classes:
[Source files](https://github.com/KulahaRoman/ObserverPattern)

Comment: You'd better off using [boost::signals2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663490/how-and-why-one-would-use-boost-signals2)...

Comment: Please add a [*Minimal*, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here if you could.

Comment: @Chipster Updated github repos